# QEMU AARCH64 "virt" Machine SMP CPUs Starting in "running" vs. "halted" State

Tags: qemu, arm64

I'm working on bare-metal.  No Linux, libraries, etc.  I'm writing processor boot code in ASM and jumping to my compiled C code.

My command line is:

```
% qemu-system-aarch64 \
   -s -S \
   -machine virt,secure=on,virtualization=on \
   -cpu cortex-a53 \
   -d int \
   -m 512M \
   -smp 4 \
   -display none \
   -nographic \
   -semihosting \
   -serial mon:stdio \
   -kernel my_file.elf \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=0 \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=1 \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=2 \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=3 \
   ;
```

When I connect gcc at the beginning, I can see:

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id     Frame
 * 1   Thread 1.1 (CPU#0 [running]) _start () at .../start.S:20
   2   Thread 1.2 (CPU#1 [halted ]) _start () at .../start.S:20
   3   Thread 1.3 (CPU#2 [halted ]) _start () at .../start.S:20
   4   Thread 1.4 (CPU#3 [halted ]) _start () at .../start.S:20
```

I want those other three processors to start in the "running" state, not "halted".  How?

Note that my DTS contains this section:

```
psci {
    migrate = < 0xc4000005 >;
    cpu_on = < 0xc4000003 >;
    cpu_off = < 0x84000002 >;
    cpu_suspend = < 0xc4000001 >;
    method = "smc";
    compatible = "arm,psci-0.2\0arm,psci";
};
```

However, I'm not sure what to do with that.  Adding many different lines of this form, don't seem to help:

```
-device loader,addr=0xc4000003,data=0x80000000,data-len=4
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with this [ARM PSCI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0022d/Power_State_Coordination_Interface_PDD_v1_1_DEN0022D.pdf) thing?  ARM's specification seems to define the "interface", not the system "implementation".  However, I don't see the PSCI as "real" registers mentioned in the "virt" documentation/source.  There is no "SMC" device mentioned in the DTS.

How does QEMU decide whether an SMP processor is "running" or "halted" on start and how can I influence that?

---

Based on @Peter-Maydell's answer below, I need to do one of two things...

1. Switch "-kernel" to "-bios".  I do this, but my code doesn't load as I expect.  My *.elf file has several sections; some in FLASH and some in DDR (above 0x40000000).  Maybe that's the problem?
2. Change my boot code to setup and issue the SMC instruction to make the ARM PSCI "CPU_ON" call that QEMU will recognize and powerup the other processors.  *Code like this runs but doesn't seem to "do" anything...*

   ```
   ldr   w0, =0xc4000003   // CPU_ON code from the DTS file
   mov   x1, 1             // CPU #1 in cluster zero (format of MPIDR register?)
   ldr   x2, _boot         // Jump address 0x40006000 (FYI)
   mov   x3, 1             // context ID (meaningful only to caller)
   smc   #0                // GO!
   // result is in x0 -> PSCI_RET_INVALID_PARAMS
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the board model -- generally we follow what the hardware does, and some boards start all CPUs from power-on, and some don't. For the 'virt' board (which is specific to QEMU) what we generally do is use PSCI, which is the Arm standard firmware interface for powering SMP CPUs up and down (among other things; you can also use it for 'power down entire machine', for instance). On startup only the primary CPU is running, and it's the job of guest code to use the PSCI API to start the secondaries. That's what that psci node in the DTS is telling the guest -- it tells the guest what specific form of the PSCI ABI QEMU implements, and in particular whether the guest should use the 'hvc' or 'smc' instruction to call PSCI functions. What QEMU is doing here is emulating a "hardware + firmware" combination -- the guest executes an 'smc' instruction and QEMU performs the actions that on real hardware would be performed by a bit of firmware code running at EL3.

The virt board does also have another mode of operation which is intended for when you want to run a guest which is itself EL3 firmware (for instance if you want to run OVMF/UEFI at EL3). If you start QEMU with -machine secure=true to enable EL3 emulation and you also provide a guest firmware blob via either -bios or -drive if=pflash,..., then QEMU will assume your firmware wants to run at EL3 and provide PSCI services itself, so it will start with all CPUs powered on and let the firmware deal with sorting them out.

A simple example of making a PSCI call to turn on another CPU (in this case cpu #4 of 8):

```
    .equ PSCI_0_2_FN64_CPU_ON, 0xc4000003
    ldr x0, =PSCI_0_2_FN64_CPU_ON
    ldr x1, =4         /* target CPU's MPIDR affinity */
    ldr x2, =0x10000   /* entry point */
    ldr x3, =0         /* context ID: put into target CPU's x0 */
    smc 0
```

Comment: Switching from "-kernel" to "-bios" seemed to make the difference.  I now get all four CPUs in "running" state.  Indeed my code is intended to disambiguate the CPU instances and jumps them to different code.

Comment: Switching from "-kernel" to "-bios" seems to have also taken my start from EL3 down to something else.  I get EL3 exceptions with the very first instruction (just a MOV).  Hmm...

Comment: @Frant...  I'm switching to the SMC flavor approach that "@Peter Maydell" mentions.  Avoiding the complexity/completeness of the ARM Trusted Firmware, I'm looking for an example of how to issue the SMC intstructions I need...

Comment: @Lance E.T. Compte: you should find the information that is you need here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/psci.txt and here: https://static.docs.arm.com/den0022/d/Power_State_Coordination_Interface_PDD_v1_1_DEN0022D.pdf, and here  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0028b/ARM_DEN0028B_SMC_Calling_Convention.pdf. I have not been using PSCI myself yet. SMC #0 with the correct register values should work (cpu_on = < 0xc4000003).

Comment: @Lance E.T. Compte: see section 5.1.4 CPU_ON of https://static.docs.arm.com/den0022/d/Power_State_Coordination_Interface_PDD_v1_1_DEN0022D.pdf. W0 should contain 0xC4000003 O I guess, and the other described in this section parameters should be set for the SMC64 version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200920/discussion-between-frant-and-lance-e-t-compte).

Comment: Note that using SMC does *not* imply using Arm Trusted Firmware -- QEMU provides the PSCI interface itself, not by running ATF. I've added a quick example of usage to the answer.

Comment: What's the `guest firmware blob` are for `virt` arm

Comment: It's whatever you want it to be. The standard off-the-shelf choice is UEFI, or maybe Trusted Firmware.

Answer (score 2):

Using the response provided by [Peter Maydell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4499941/peter-maydell), I am providing here a Minimal, Reproducible Example for people who may be interested.

Downloading/installing aarch64-elf toolchain:

```
wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/8.3-2019.03/binrel/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-elf.tar.xz?revision=d678fd94-0ac4-485a-8054-1fbc60622a89&la=en"
mkdir -p /opt/arm
tar Jxf gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-elf.tar.xz -C /opt/arm
```

Example files:

loop.s:

```
                .title "loop.s"
                .arch armv8-a
                .text
                .global Reset_Handler
Reset_Handler:  mrs x0, mpidr_el1
                and x0,x0, 0b11
                cmp x0, #0
                b.eq Core0
                cmp x0, #1
                b.eq Core1
                cmp x0, #2
                b.eq Core2
                cmp x0, #3
                b.eq Core3
Error:          b .
Core0:          b .
Core1:          b .
Core2:          b .
Core3:          b .
               .end
```

build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf-
AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}as
LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld
OBJCOPY=${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy
OBJDUMP=${CROSS_COMPILE}objdump

${AS} -g -o loop.o loop.s 
${LD} -g -gc-sections -g -e Reset_Handler -Ttext-segment=0x40004000 -Map=loop.map -o loop.elf loop.o
${OBJDUMP} -d loop.elf
```

qemu.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
QEMU_SYSTEM_AARCH64=qemu-system-aarch64
${QEMU_SYSTEM_AARCH64} \
   -s -S \
   -machine virt,secure=on,virtualization=on \
   -cpu cortex-a53 \
   -d int \
   -m 512M \
   -smp 4 \
   -display none \
   -nographic \
   -semihosting \
   -serial mon:stdio \
   -bios loop.elf \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=0 \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=1 \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=2 \
   -device loader,addr=0x40004000,cpu-num=3 \
   ;
```

loop.gdb:

```
target remote localhost:1234
file loop.elf
load loop.elf
disassemble Reset_Handler
info threads
continue
```

debug.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf-
GDB=${CROSS_COMPILE}gdb

${GDB} --command=loop.gdb
```

Executing the program - two consoles will be needed.

First console:

```
./build.sh
```

Output should look like:

```
/opt/arm/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf-ld: warning: address of `text-segment' isn't multiple of maximum page size

loop.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000040004000 <Reset_Handler>:
    40004000:   d53800a0        mrs     x0, mpidr_el1
    40004004:   92400400        and     x0, x0, #0x3
    40004008:   f100001f        cmp     x0, #0x0
    4000400c:   54000100        b.eq    4000402c <Core0>  // b.none
    40004010:   f100041f        cmp     x0, #0x1
    40004014:   540000e0        b.eq    40004030 <Core1>  // b.none
    40004018:   f100081f        cmp     x0, #0x2
    4000401c:   540000c0        b.eq    40004034 <Core2>  // b.none
    40004020:   f1000c1f        cmp     x0, #0x3
    40004024:   540000a0        b.eq    40004038 <Core3>  // b.none

0000000040004028 <Error>:
    40004028:   14000000        b       40004028 <Error>

000000004000402c <Core0>:
    4000402c:   14000000        b       4000402c <Core0>

0000000040004030 <Core1>:
    40004030:   14000000        b       40004030 <Core1>

0000000040004034 <Core2>:
    40004034:   14000000        b       40004034 <Core2>

0000000040004038 <Core3>:
    40004038:   14000000        b       40004038 <Core3>
```

Then:

```
./qemu.sh
```

Second console:

```
./debug.sh
```

Output should look like:

```
GNU gdb (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 8.3-2019.03 (arm-rel-8.36)) 8.2.1.20190227-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-elf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.linaro.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support
determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.
0x0000000040004000 in ?? ()
Loading section .text, size 0x3c lma 0x40004000
Start address 0x40004000, load size 60
Transfer rate: 480 bits in <1 sec, 60 bytes/write.
Dump of assembler code for function Reset_Handler:
=> 0x0000000040004000 <+0>:     mrs     x0, mpidr_el1
   0x0000000040004004 <+4>:     and     x0, x0, #0x3
   0x0000000040004008 <+8>:     cmp     x0, #0x0
   0x000000004000400c <+12>:    b.eq    0x4000402c <Core0>  // b.none
   0x0000000040004010 <+16>:    cmp     x0, #0x1
   0x0000000040004014 <+20>:    b.eq    0x40004030 <Core1>  // b.none
   0x0000000040004018 <+24>:    cmp     x0, #0x2
   0x000000004000401c <+28>:    b.eq    0x40004034 <Core2>  // b.none
   0x0000000040004020 <+32>:    cmp     x0, #0x3
   0x0000000040004024 <+36>:    b.eq    0x40004038 <Core3>  // b.none
End of assembler dump.
  Id   Target Id                    Frame 
* 1    Thread 1.1 (CPU#0 [running]) Reset_Handler () at loop.s:5
  2    Thread 1.2 (CPU#1 [running]) Reset_Handler () at loop.s:5
  3    Thread 1.3 (CPU#2 [running]) Reset_Handler () at loop.s:5
  4    Thread 1.4 (CPU#3 [running]) Reset_Handler () at loop.s:5
```

All four cores are stopped at address `0x40004000/Reset_Handler`, and were started by the `continue` command in loop.gdb.
Press `CTRL+C` in the second console:

```
^C
Thread 1 received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
Core0 () at loop.s:16
16      Core0:                  b .
(gdb)
```

Core #0 was executing code at Core0 label.
Enter the following command (still in the second console):

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id                    Frame 
* 1    Thread 1.1 (CPU#0 [running]) Core0 () at loop.s:16
  2    Thread 1.2 (CPU#1 [running]) Core1 () at loop.s:17
  3    Thread 1.3 (CPU#2 [running]) Core2 () at loop.s:18
  4    Thread 1.4 (CPU#3 [running]) Core3 () at loop.s:19
(gdb)
```

Cores #1,#2 and #3 were executing the code at the respective Core1, Core2, Core3 labels prior to be stopped by the `CTRL+C`.

Description of the `MPIDR_EL1` register is available [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0500j/BABHBJCI.html): the two lasts bits of `MPIDR_EL1.Aff0` were used by all four cores for determining their respective core numbers.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Note that keeping your secondary CPUs in a plain "branch to self" loop like that will eat host CPU emulating them spinning. If that's a problem then you can add a 'wfi' to the loop (and then the "wake up a secondary" code the primary runs should involve sending the secondary an interrupt). Watch out that the secondary codepath then needs to include "enable my interrupt controller interface" before it goes to sleep on the 'wfi' if you do this!

Comment: @Peter Maydell: thank you very much for the extra and very useful information, I clearly understand my example is a little bit too crude for real-life, even though its scope was strictly restricted to showing that the four cores had been following their respective code paths when starting qemu with the `-bios` option.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that, just thought I'd add in the extra info about something to consider when extending the simple example into a more real-world use. Though if you always boot all the secondary cores within a few seconds of bootup the CPU usage is insignificant.